# How can I test overdispersion in STATA when using xtpoisson and xtnbreg?

Tags: stata

I have balanced panel data and my dependent variable is count one which distribution has lots of zero(0).
therefore I think it might be suitable for using negative binomial regression rather than poisson one. However, I cannot find how can I test whether xtnbreg or xtpoisson is suitable for my data.

If someone can help how can I test overdispersion to choose poisson model or nbmodel.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if anything it is a statistical question. There is no sharp or precise programming question here.

Comment: I would ask on Statalist.

Comment: Or transfer this question on Cross-Validated.

Comment: Hint: what you should do depends on what is your objective.